# ssh.service keeps restating forever

Tags: raspbian, ssh, systemd

On my rpi machine

```
pi@pi2 ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Release:        9.9
Codename:       stretch
```

I observe in my logs that `ssh.service` keeps restarting over and over.

```
sudo journalctl -f
```

```
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.                
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 sshd[6396]: Received signal 15; terminating.                                    
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.                        
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 sshd[6399]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 15 17:05:20 pi2 sshd[6399]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jul 15 17:06:06 pi2 sshd[5532]: Received disconnect from 192.168.178.23: 11: disconnected by user
Jul 15 17:06:08 pi2 sshd[6403]: Did not receive identification string from 192.168.178.23
Jul 15 17:06:09 pi2 sshd[6404]: Accepted publickey for ibqn from 192.168.178.23 port 52626 ssh2
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 sshd[6399]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 sshd[6432]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jul 15 17:06:51 pi2 sshd[6432]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

It seems to me that `systemd` does not get notified that `sshd` is running properly and restarts it again...
Do you have any ideas who to resolve this issue?

```
pi@pi2 ~ $ sudo systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2019-07-15 17:24:57 CEST; 1min 4s ago
  Process: 6737 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6739 (sshd)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
```